# Get PDF file from Nodejs and have copy in angular physical directory

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, angular6, pdf-viewer

I have an angular application that has a feature to render the pdf in the client side with the help of ng2-pdfviewer, that reads the file from the local directory from the client side.

Now I have an upload option which uploads the pdf files to the server and storing it in local uploads directory in the server side. Now I want to read the physical pdf file available in the server instead of downloading as blob and saving.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer#src) accepts both an `UInt8Array` (that fits your former approach on reading from a file utilising `FileReader`, for instance) or a `string` (that can contain a remote URL) on its `src` parameter.

So, as far as you have the complete URL for your target PDF, you can provide it as the source for rendering.